# Can i combine html5shiv.js and respond.min.js into one file?

Tags: javascript

I just wonder if I can combine whit two files into one .js file?

```
<!--[if (lt IE 9)&(!IEMobile)]><script src="./js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if (lt IE 9)&(!IEMobile)]><script src="./js/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, simply copy and paste both files into a single file and update your reference in the javascript src tag.

Having a smaller number of files results in fewer requests!

To eliminate any errors use the commands below to ensure you don't miss anything from either file:

Linux:    cat file1.js file2.js > combined.js
Windows:  type file1.js file2.js > combined.js

Comment: Thanks. Fewer request was the reason I want this. Thanks again

Comment: There would be very slight improvements.  I have updated original answer to include linux and windows commands to achieve what you are after.